# Tip Calculator - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm just starting out in Swift, and wanted to make a tip calculator. But I'm running into some issues and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. In the `getBillAmt` function, my total isn't updating/displaying, it only displays the `billAmt` I've tried a a few different options to get the total to update, but can't get it. My most recent attempt in below.

In my previous attempts my issues were not being able to convert Int to Float.

Variables,

`var tipPercentAmt = Int()`

`var billAmt = Float() //bill before tip`

`var total = Float()`

Slider, where user can slide to a tip amount (as an int)

```
@IBAction func tipAmtVal(sender: UISlider) {
    let tipPercentAmt = Int(sender.value)
}
```

And, getting the bill amount from the user, from a text field (as a float) and then adding the tip to it to display the total in a label

```
@IBAction func getBillAmt(sender: UITextField) {
    let billAmt = Float(billAmtText.text!)
    let total = billAmt! + (Float(tipPercentAmt / 100)
    tipAmtLabel.text = "\(total)"
}

//cause labels to update when user hits return
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to trigger your `getBillAmt` function?

Comment: BTW - You need to stop and learn about Swift optionals. All of those `!` you are using are just going to cause your app to crash.

Comment: When the user hits the return button, sorry forgot to add to question.

Comment: You are not using sender in the getBillAmt function, and also in that function if billAmt is a consonant (let) you don't need the ! when you do " let total=billAmt!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is setup to actually call your `getBillAmt` function. Assuming your text field is setup properly with its delegate, the `textFieldShouldReturn` function will be called and that's it.

You need to call your `getBillAmount` from there.

```
func getBillAmt(textField: UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text {
        if let billAmt = Float(text) {
            let total = billAmt + (Float(tipPercentAmt / 100)
            tipAmtLabel.text = "\(total)"
        }
    }
}

//cause labels to update when user hits return
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    getBillAmt(textField: textField)

    return false
}
```

As you can see I've made some other fixes too.

Comment: With the line of `let total = billAmt`, I get an error of, Value of optional type Float? not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! or ?, this is the same error I was getting earlier.

Comment: Oops. Need a 2nd `if` since the conversion from string to float can fail if the text doesn't actually contain a valid number. See my update.

Comment: Oh! Okay! Thank you!